# Errors 1. GreaterEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.2 -0.4 I attempted. 2. RegionPlot3D::boolf:must be a Boolean function

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, regions

I am trying to plot this inequality

```
RegionPlot3D[
 1/(1 + 2 (-(t2 + t4) + Sqrt[(t2 + t4)^2 + 4 (t2 t4 - (1/2 (2* t1 + t2 + t4 - 1))^2)])) >= 0, {t1, 0, 1}, {t2, 0, 1}, {t4, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a test of the argument to `Sqrt` to enforce it being positive before the inequality is checked:

```
RegionPlot3D[(t2 + t4)^2 + 4 (t2 t4 - (1/2 (2*t1 + t2 + t4 - 1))^2) > 
   0 && 1/(1 + 
      2 (-(t2 + t4) + 
         Sqrt[(t2 + t4)^2 + 
           4 (t2 t4 - (1/2 (2*t1 + t2 + t4 - 1))^2)])) >= 0,
 {t1, 0, 1}, {t2, 0, 1}, {t4, 0, 1}]
```

[image]